# Dynamic element translation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Say I've got a large div, and depending on the users mouse position, I want the position of the div to change. I'm trying to work out the most efficient way of doing this.

Currently I'm getting the mouse position, calculating the x and y speeds, and then starting a loop which moves the element pixel by pixel according to the calculated speeds. The div may have lots of content and I'm thinking this loop might slow things down too much.

Is there any way to do this a little more efficiently? Should I use webworkers?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to animate the relocation?

Comment: Yes, I suppose what I want is an Age of Empires-type scrolling effect. When the mouse moves to the edge of the screen the div pans around. As the mouse gets closer to the edge, it pans faster

Comment: By `starting a loop` please tell me you mean `start a setTimeout loop`

Comment: Genius. I actually haven't implemented the above strategy yet, was just attempting that... I'm a little new with this stuff. Will this method slow down the average computer noticeably?